# How to define a class method :[] when using class_eval

Tags: ruby, quaternions

I am using the [quaternion gem](https://github.com/tanahiro/quaternion) and want to define a class method for the :[] operator that creates a new Quaternion from an array.  I have tried

```
Quaternion.class_eval do
  def self.[ary]
    Quaternion.new(*ary)
  end
end
```

but this gives a syntax error. How do I do this?

Comment: The docs for [Methods](https://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html) contains examples for defining  operator methods, including `[]` and `[]=`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method's *name* is `[]`, but it still takes its argument list in the usual way

```
def self.[](ary)
  ...
end
```

Then you call it as `Quaternion[ary]`

Answer (score 4):

So long story short to be able to make use of `Quaternion[arg]` you want to define it like below

```rb
  def self.[](arg)
    Quaternion.new(*ary)
  end
```

interesting is, why does it work?
Well it's syntactic sugar that ruby has

doing `foo[bar]` is the same as `foo.[](bar)`

`foo[bar]=baz` is the same as `foo.[]=(bar, baz)`

and `a + b` is actually `a.+(b)`

If you want to define it, it will look like this:

```rb
def [](key)
  ...
end

def []=(key, value)
  ...
end

def +(arg)
  ...
end
```

It's because method names in ruby can have special characters.

If you are interested in how internally it gets tokenized and parsed you can read Ruby Under Microscope which is a great introduction to the subject. There is also this free book I've found which also touches on the topic -> https://ruby-hacking-guide.github.io/ (check chapter 8 section Method Calls)

Comment: *"moreover doing foo[bar]=baz is the same as foo.[](bar, baz)"* missed an equals sign here. Should read **"moreover doing foo[bar]=baz is the same as foo.[]=(bar, baz)"** and make the OP aware that they object would have to define a method as `def []=(idx_or_key, value)`

Comment: you're right. I've missed that equal sign. Thanks for pointing that out :)